# Handling empty style tags with styled-components streaming SSR

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, server-side-rendering, styled-components

I set up streaming SSR for styled-components as outlined here: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#streaming-rendering

It works fine when a given route actually has styled-components.

But if the route doesn't include any styled-components, it still generates a tag like

```
<style data-styled-components="" data-styled-streamed="true"></style>
```

And then React warns on hydrate():

> warning.js:33 Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a `<style>` in `<div>`.

(from `warnForDeletedHydratableElement`)

Am I supposed to filter out empty style tags from `ServerStyleSheet` somehow? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Have you ever figured this one out? :-)

Comment: @pimmey nope! seemed like a low priority thing

Comment: @pimmey Do you have any update about the warning?

Comment: @giankotarola as far as I remember, this warning was popping out when I had a component without styles (as in each component had to be a styled-component for the warning to be gone :D) but I ended up not using SSR altogether, so not sure completely.